# Eyeshot FPS is low in perspective projection

Tags: eyeshot

If I use a high resolution image (about 15000 * 15000) and perspective projection then the scene is very slow (FPS is low).
If set the Orthographic projection then the FPS is high
What needs to be done so that the FPS in the perspective projection is also high?

[projectionType.Orthographic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8Zpy.gif)

[projectionType.Perspective](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2E7t3.gif)

Comment: https://devdept.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360016436713-Performance-Tips

Comment: @DanielLord Thanks for the link. I tried all the described methods to see performance, but nothing helped

Comment: Perspective should always be faster than orthographic for shapes. For image it's the inverse. You need to know that a 15,000x15,000 picture is EXTREMELY heavy. That one entity of nearly 1 gigabyte. You need to reduce its size or split it into smaller one.